# How to test performance of the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want details time taken for the execution of the stored procedure.
I have tried by cleaning DB cache, but getting difference in seconds resolution only.

Is there any build in method or tool of SQL server to get the detail statistics for the performance of the stored procedure?

Comment: You can always use "execution plan", shortcut should be CTRL + L ... it shows details how your procedure is doing, if you go through the toolbar it's written "Include Actual Execution Plan"

Comment: In an SSMS query window, create a datetime variable = getDate().  Run your procedure.  Then use datediff to get the number of milliseconds between getDate() and your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler) to capture information (including duration) about SP and individual queries in it. You can also use [Display An Actual Execution Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan) to how your queries are executed.

- To launch a profiler from SSMS go to Tools->"SQL Server Profiler"
- To
  "Display An Actual Execution Plan" go to Query->"Display An Actual
  Execution Plan"